# Как создать уникальный поток на каждого пользователя?

Tags: node.js, socket.io

Добрый вечер, день.

Правильная система обновлений как у вконтакте.

У меня есть старая система обновлений я ее обновляю на новую с помощью `socket.io` и `now.js`, так вот мне нужно создать уникальный поток на каждого пользователя, думаю через обычный массив.

А можете вы подсказать, как грамотней создавать поток на каждого пользователя?

Comment: Что в данном случае означает слово "поток" ?

Answer (score 3):

Я, конечно, не эксперт в Node.js, но думаю, что правильного способа для создания выделенного потока каждому пользователю не существует. По крайней мере, это явным образом противоречит заявленной идеологии Node.js. Насколько я понимаю, это асинхронный сервер, управляемый событиями. По большому счёту, его основная идея состоит в том, чтобы так не делать, т.е. не создавать по потоку на пользователя.