# Нужно переместить первую строку файла в конец

Tags: node.js

Думаю так: взять первую строку из файла, присвоить её переменной, удалить из файла и положить в конец.

```
const fs = require('fs');

// Читаем строку
fs.readFile('file.txt', (err, data) => {
    if (err) {
        throw err;
    }
    const EOL = require('os').EOL;
    let fileRows = data.toString().split(EOL);
    // Присваиваем переменной
    let firstRow = fileRows.shift();
    fileRows.push(firstRow);
    const fileData = new Uint8Array(Buffer.from(fileRows.join(EOL)));
    // Удаляем и пишем в конец
    fs.writeFile('file.txt', fileData, (err) => {
        if (err) {
            throw err;
        }
    });
    // Выводим значение переменной
    console.log(firstRow);
});
```

Можно это сделать эффективнее?

Comment: Это заказ или вопрос?

Comment: Удалить строку регуляркой проще простого.

Comment: Всем спасибо за ответы! Я после (простите) zennoposter не ожидал что подобный вопрос тянет на заказ. Вообще мне нужно просто запустить порядка 10-ти потоков с разными данными через модуль cluster. Вероятно мне стоило так и спросить.. Сейчас буду что-то делать =) Всем спасибо ещё раз!

Comment: слушай, ну Yaant и я тебе рассказали как правильно решается такая задача по изменению файла. может по кластеру стоит открыть другой вопрос, а этот привести к изначальной формулировке? а то не вяжутся наши пояснения к потокам к тому, что в твоём коде одновременно 5 вокеров пытаются читать-писать один и тот же файл.

Comment: Вопрос вернул, ответ принял, открою другой

Comment: давай. только ты сам сначала подумай, я на проблему указал в предыдущем комменте

Comment: Всё оказалось проще https://repl.it/@bezvozni/cluster

Comment: У меня только вопрос не противоречит ли это самой идеи node.js https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/145976/310983 =))

Comment: @Ars, зря ты снёс свой сегодняшний вопрос. Заходи в [чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/22462/stack-overflow--), расскажешь какую задачу ты решаешь.

Comment: @nörbörnën не хватает репутации для чата, из-за неё ж и снёс, вернул на место, но я пока выкрутился вроде, написал там как.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

---

Очевидно, что это задачка на работу с потоками.

Особенность моего решения, в отличие от решения Yaant, - не используется временный файл, а существующий перезаписывается с 0вой стартовой позиции. Это решение будет особенно выгодно когда файл большого размера, а места на диске не достаточно.

```
const fs = require('fs');

const filepath = process.argv[2];
if (!filepath) {
    console.log('\nДолжен быть указан путь к существующему файлу!\n');
    process.exit(1);
}
console.log(`FILE: ${filepath}`);

let buffer;
const readStream = fs.createReadStream(filepath);
readStream.on('error', (err) => {
    console.error('READING ERROR!!!');
    console.trace(err);
    process.exit(1);
})
.on('data', (b) => {
    buffer = buffer ? Buffer.concat([buffer, b]) : b;
    readStream.pause();
    const pos = buffer.indexOf('\n');
    if (pos === -1) {
        readStream.resume();
        return;
    }

    let firstLine = buffer.slice(0, pos);
    let newlineSymbol = '\n';
    if (firstLine.indexOf('\r') > -1) {
        firstLine = firstLine.slice(0, firstLine.length - 1);
        newlineSymbol = '\r\n';
    }
    const restLine = buffer.slice(pos+1, buffer.length);

    const writeStream = fs.createWriteStream(filepath, {start: 0, flags: 'a'});
    writeStream.on('error', (err) => {
        console.error('WRITING ERROR!!!');
        console.trace(err);
        process.exit(1);
    });
    readStream.removeAllListeners('data');
    readStream.once('end', () => {
        writeStream.write(newlineSymbol);
        writeStream.end(firstLine);
    });
    writeStream.write(restLine);
    readStream.pipe(writeStream);
});
```

Путь к файлу передаётся при запуске программы вот так:

> node program.js /path/to/test.file.name.json

Comment: Единственное замечание - обычно все-таки свободного места на диске больше, чем оперативной памяти. А тут файл полностью считывается в память. Для ОЧЕНЬ больших файлов это может оказаться проблемой. :)

Comment: @Yaant, привет! буфер копится до первого переноса строки, достигнуть размера файла он может только если не встретит `\n`. я об этом думал, но решил в ответе не писать обработчик этой ситуации чтобы не усложнять код. ну и, должен сказать, что твоё решение тоже страдает этой проблемой так как ты тоже не знаешь длину строки.

Comment: @Yaant если же ты не это имел ввиду то обоснуй за "тут файл полностью считывается в память"! у меня после обнаружения `\n` чтение чанками `readStream.pipe(writeStream)`

Comment: А, ну да. :) Замечание снимается. :)

Comment: @Yaant му-ха-ха, бро! :)

Comment: Да это моя невнимательность, поторопился, отреагировал на `buffer = buffer ? Buffer.concat([buffer, b]) : b;` :)

Comment: Однако любопытно, кто так усердно минусует? :)

Comment: @Yaant да вообще капец. мне за ответ прилетело три минуса. мы уже и в чятике обсудили этих безмолвных минусаторов.

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/83935/discussion-between-yaant-and-norbornen).

Answer (score 1):

Как-то так:

```
const readline = require('readline');
const fs = require('fs');
let firstLine;
let filename = 'file.txt';
let tmpfilename = 'file.tmp';
let tmpfile = fs.createWriteStream(tmpfilename);
let rl = readline.createInterface({input : fs.createReadStream(filename)});
rl.on('line', line => {
    if (firstLine == undefined) {
        firstLine = line;
    } else {
        tmpfile.write(line + require('os').EOL);
    }
});
rl.on('close', () => {
    tmpfile.write(firstLine);
    fs.unlinkSync(filename);
    fs.renameSync(tmpfilename, filename);
});
```

Comment: Ты похоже не в курсе чем const от let отличается...