# Node.js удалить строку из потока файла

Tags: node.js

Предположим у меня есть лог-файл с миллиардами строк, которые не уместятся все за раз в оперативной памяти, чтобы обработать их оттуда и, к тому же, мне важна скорость работы скрипта, ибо это сервер с кучей запросов в секунду.

Новые данные в этот лог заносятся при помощи `fs.appendFile`, а считывание производится построчно потоком, выстроенным при помощи [fs-reverse](https://www.npmjs.com/package/fs-reverse).

Как при считывании файла построчным потоком (как с начала файла, так и наоборот) при определённых условиях удалить текущую строку? Например я хочу удалить десять последних строчек в логе, в которых встретится слово `test`?

Comment: Никак. Чтобы удалить, надо записать весь конец файла повторно.

Comment: @Qwertiy ого, мне тогда стало интересно, а базы данных, которые работают НЕ по принципу REDIS тоже вынуждены целые таблицы при каждом запросе заново перезаписывать?

Comment: Нет, БД выделяют фиксированный размер под строку и просто помечают её как удалённую. А потом когда-нибудь на её место новую строку запишут.

Comment: я отвечал на такой же вопрос тут https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/887904/%D0%9D%D1%83%D0%B6%D0%BD%D0%BE-%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B2%D1%83%D1%8E-%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BA%D1%83-%D1%84%D0%B0%D0%B9%D0%BB%D0%B0-%D0%B2-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B5%D1%86/887972#887972

Comment: @nörbörnën в вашем примере, по сути, происходит добавление строк в конец файла, этого же можно добиться и с `appendFile` методом. Мне же нужно точечно заменить строку в определённом месте в файле, в миллиард первой позиции, например, не перезаписывая весь файл целиком. Покопавшись во флагах я, вроде как, осознал, что операционные системы впринципе не умеют делать то, что я хочу, так что придётся мастерить костыли размерами с эфилеву башню.

Comment: А стандартный вариант с ограничением размера лог-файла чем не угодил?

Comment: @Qwertiy я, на самом деле, вовсе и не лог файл хотел сделать, а простейшую однофайловую базу, с записями в ней json формата разбитых по строкам. Хоть база нужна и простая, но запросов и данных планируется много, а создание нового файла, по моим ощущениям, раз в сто медленнее просто добавления строки в конец файла. Собственно благодаря второму вашему комментарию здесь, я разобрался в особенностях работы жёсткого диска и теперь планирую сделать разделение структуры и данных, а среди данных разделение на типы по количеству символов в одной записи и склеивать это всё ссылками. Вроде так правильнее